# Chunk data with Conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit, network-conduit

Here is an example of a `conduit` combinator that supposed to `yield` downstream when a complete message is received from upstream:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Combinators
import Data.Conduit.Network

message :: Monad m => ConduitT BS.ByteString BS.ByteString m ()
message = loop
  where
    loop = await >>= maybe (return ()) go
    go x = if (BS.isSuffixOf "|" x)
        then yield (BS.init x) >> loop
        else leftover x
```

Server code itself looks like following:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  runTCPServer (serverSettings 5000 "!4") $ \ appData -> runConduit $
    (appSource appData)
    .| message
    .| (appSink appData)
```

For some reason `telnet 127.0.0.1 5000` disconnects after sending any message:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
123|
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Please advice, what am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

More importantly what I try doing here is wait for completion signal `|` and then `yield` the complete message downstream. Here is the evolution of `message` combinator:

```
message :: Monad m => ConduitT BS.ByteString BS.ByteString m ()
message = do
  minput <- await
  case minput of
    Nothing    -> return ()
    Just input -> do
      case BS.breakSubstring "|" input of
        ("", "")  -> return ()
        ("", "|") -> return ()
        ("", xs)  -> leftover $ BS.tail xs
        (x, "")   -> leftover x -- problem is in this leftover
        (x, xs)   -> do
          yield x
          leftover $ BS.tail xs
      message
```

The idea I had is that if there is nothing coming from the upstream combinator will have to wait until there will be something, such that it can send a complete message downstream. But it seams that `conduit` starts spinning on CPU a lot on that `leftover` call in the above `message` combinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out that it was necessary to `await` instead of `leftover` on the base case. Here is how working `message` combinator looks like:

```
message :: Monad m => ConduitT BS.ByteString BS.ByteString m ()
message = do
  minput <- await
  case minput of
    Nothing    -> return ()
    Just input -> process input >> message
  where
    process input =
      case BS.breakSubstring "|" input of
        ("", "")  -> return ()
        ("", "|") -> return ()
        ("", xs)  -> leftover $ BS.tail xs
        (x, "")   -> do
          minput <- await
          case minput of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just newInput -> process $ BS.concat [x, newInput]
        (x, xs)   -> do
          yield x
          leftover $ BS.tail xs
```

> A bit of boilerplate that can probably be cleaned up, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Print `x` in `go` to debug.

```
  ...
  go x = do
    liftIO (Prelude.print x)
    if ...
```

The socket receives a bytestring that ends with `\r\n`, so you go to the `else` branch, which terminates the session.

Comment: Indeed `\r\n` might have got in the way, but in the end it is somehow connected to the `leftover` call. I updated original question.